# ¿Ayuda,Tengo problemas al inicializar mi datatable y una función campos dinámicos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un datatable y el botón dentro de un modal que agrega `<select>` 
 e `<input>` dinámicos y al seleccionar una opción del `<select>` se omitirá la opción en la próxima selección pero al cargar mi datatable la función mencionada anteriormente deja de funcionar y he detectado que al comentar el método que carga mi tabla vuelve a funcionar bien mi función de agregar.

Cuando ambos están declarados mi función `MantProyecto.botonAgregar();` deja de funcionar.

Tener en cuenta que el método `MantProyecto.cargar_tabla()` funciona a la perfección.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    MantProyecto.botonAgregar();
    MantProyecto.cargar_tabla();
});
```

este es el json listatabla.json que carga la tabla

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "NroCarga": 100005,
            "NroTransferencia": 100005,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 2.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 2.00,
                "ManoObra": 2.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 2.00,
                "Depreciacion": 15.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568733322841"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100038,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 32.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 4.00,
                "ManoObra": 0.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 0.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568739619037"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100122,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 4.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 4.00,
                "ManoObra": 4.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 4.00,
                "Depreciacion": 70.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568733739782"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100210,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 12.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 21.00,
                "ManoObra": 21.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 21.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568846197568"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100211,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 21.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 2.00,
                "ManoObra": 3.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 4.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568846292214"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 103546,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 1.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 1.00,
                "ManoObra": 0.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 0.00,
                "Depreciacion": 6.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568737123144"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 103569,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 10.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 10.00,
                "ManoObra": 10.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 10.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568824943240"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 103569,
            "NroTransferencia": 100150,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 2.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 2.00,
                "ManoObra": 2.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 2.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568846459043"
        }
    ]
}
```

Este es el json listacombo.json para el select dinámico

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "1",
            "descripcion_breve": "AMORTIZACION DE SOFTWARE",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "2",
            "descripcion_breve": "DA DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO \r\n",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "3",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "4",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE EQUIPOS DIVERSOS",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "5",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE INFRAESTRUCTURA",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "6",
            "descripcion_breve": "DEPREC.DE MUEB.Y ENSERES",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        },
        {
            "IdTabla": null,
            "IdCatalogo": null,
            "id_sub_catalogo": "7",
            "descripcion_breve": "DA DEPRECIACION ASIGNADA",
            "Valor1": null,
            "Valor2": null,
            "Valor3": null,
            "Valor4": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Mi html

```
<section class="container">
        <div class="container mb-4">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center titulo-facturacion">
                <h3 id="tituloPrincipal"> MANTENIMIENTO DE PROYECTOS </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnNuevo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Nuevo</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <div class="">

                    <table cellpadding="0"
                           cellspacing="0"
                           border="0"
                           class="table table-bordered"
                           id="tabla_mantProyecto" style="font-size:10px; width:100%">
                        <thead class="alert-primary">
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>N° Carga</th>
                                <th>N° Transferencia</th>
                                <th>Ingresos</th>
                                <th>Costo Bienes</th>
                                <th>Mano Obra</th>
                                <th>Gastos Generales</th>
                                <th>Depreciacion</th>
                                <th>Accion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tarifaproyecto"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- Modal 2-->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-sc" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                            <label for="descripcionCarga">Proyecto a Cargar</label>
                            <input type="number" id="idCargar" hidden>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcionCarga" placeholder="Cargar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck">Transferir a</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-5" id="trans">
                            <label for="descripcionTransferir" id="labeltorre">Torre</label>
                            <input type="hidden" id="idTransferir">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcionTransferir" placeholder="Transferir">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="idIngresos">Ingresos</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idIngresos" placeholder="Ingresos">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="idCostoBienes">Costo Bienes</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idCostoBienes" placeholder="Costo Bienes">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="idManoObra">Mano Obra</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idManoObra" placeholder="Mano Obra">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="idGastoGen">Gastos Generales</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idGastoGen" placeholder="Gasto Generales">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="tipoDepreciacion">Depreciacion</label>
                    <div id="items">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCerrar">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnActualizar">Actualizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero es saber porque pasa eso yo necesito que mi tabla cargue desde el principio y no afecte a la función del botón agregar

Este es mi javascript

```
var seleccionados = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    MantProyecto.init_botones();
    MantProyecto.botonAgregar();
    MantProyecto.cargar_tabla();
});

var MantProyecto = (function() {
    return {
        init_botones: function() {
            $('#btnNuevo').click(function() {
                MantProyecto.limpiar_controles();
                $('#btnGuardar').show();
                $('#btnActualizar').hide();
            });
        },
        botonAgregar:function(){

            $('#add').click(function() {
                if (seleccionados.length < 7) {
                    var valor = $('select:enabled').val();
                    valor != null ? seleccionados.push(valor) : null;
                    $('.idDepreciacion').prop('disabled', true);
                    MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
                }
                if (seleccionados.length == 6) $('#add').prop('disabled', true);
                //MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
            });
        },
        limpiar_controles: function() {
            $('#idCargar').val('');
            $('#descripcionCarga').val('');
            $('#idTransferir').val('');
            $('#descripcionTransferir').val('');
            $('#idDescripcion').val('');
            $('#idIngresos').val('');
            $('#idCostoBienes').val('');
            $('#idManoObra').val('');
            $('#idGastoGen').val('');
        },
        cargaCombo: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'listacombo.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(json) {
                    var items = document.getElementById('items');
                    //items.innerHTML += "";
                    var select = `
                            <div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                                <select class="idDepreciacion">
                            `;
                    for (let valor of json.data) {
                        if (!seleccionados.includes(valor.id_sub_catalogo))
                            select +=
                                "<option value='" +
                                valor.id_sub_catalogo +
                                "' >" +
                                valor.descripcion_breve +
                                '</option>';
                    }
                    var html =
                        select +
                        `</select> &nbsp;
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-2 valor" type="number"/>  &nbsp;     
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>
                                        </div>`;
                    $('#items').append(html);
                },
            });
        },
        cargar_tabla() {
            var table = $('#tabla_mantProyecto')
                .removeAttr('width')
                .DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: false,
                    paging: true,
                    ordering: false,
                    info: true,
                    searching: true,
                    bDestroy: true,
                    autoWidth: false,
                    ajax: {
                        url: 'listatabla.json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        datatype: 'json',
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: null,
                            orderable: false,
                        },
                        { data: 'NroCarga', orderable: false },
                        { data: 'NroTransferencia', orderable: false },
                        {
                            data: 'Ingresos',
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '),
                            orderable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'Sigeri.CostoBienes',
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '),
                            orderable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'Sigeri.ManoObra',
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '),
                            orderable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'Sigeri.GatosGenerales',
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '),
                            orderable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'Sigeri.Depreciacion',
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '),
                            orderable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                                //return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript: tarifa.fnEditarProyecto(' + full.Proyecto.IdProyecto + ');" title="Editar registro.">Editar</a>';
                                return (
                                    '<button  class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btnEditar" onClick="MantProyecto.fnEditarMantProyecto(' +
                                    full.DepreciacionId +
                                    ')">Editar</button >' +
                                    '<button  class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="btnEliminar" onClick="MantProyecto.fnEliminarMantProyecto(' +
                                    full.DepreciacionId +
                                    ')">Eliminar</button >'
                                );
                            },
                        },

                        // { data: "Tarifa", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. ') },
                    ],
                    columnDefs: [
                        {
                            sortable: false,
                            class: 'index',
                            targets: 0,
                        },
                        { width: '150', targets: 3 },
                    ],
                    language: {
                        decimal: '',
                        emptyTable: 'No hay información',
                        info: 'Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas',
                        infoEmpty: 'Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas',
                        infoFiltered: '(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)',
                        infoPostFix: '',
                        thousands: ',',
                        lengthMenu: 'Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas',
                        loadingRecords: 'Cargando...',
                        processing: 'Procesando...',
                        search: 'Buscar:',
                        zeroRecords: 'Sin resultados encontrados',
                        paginate: {
                            first: 'Primero',
                            last: 'Ultimo',
                            next: 'Siguiente',
                            previous: 'Anterior',
                        },
                    },
                });

            table
                .on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
                    table
                        .column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' })
                        .nodes()
                        .each(function(cell, i) {
                            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
                        });
                })
                .draw();
        },
    };
})();
```

En la siguiente imagen se puede observar que se repite la misma opción del `<select>` cuando no debería hacer eso, ya que la función agregar hace que se omita la opción seleccionada cuando se selecciona un segundo `<select>` y esa función se ve afectada cuando agrego el método `MantProyecto.cargar_tabla()` en el `document.ready()` ya que deja de funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedo sugerir intentar colocando `MantProyecto.cargar_tabla();` antes de `MantProyecto.botonAgregar();` luego el problema es muy extenso para tratar de resolverlo.de momento.

Comment: Agregue todo ese código si fuese necesario para que puedan probar ambas funciones que estén bien pero el problema solo porque deja de funcionar el metodo "botonAgregar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución, el problema esta en la función del botón agregar estaba señalando al `<select>` del datatable que filtra la cantidad de registros y no al `<select>` dinámico, tuve que agregarle la clase `.dep_val select:enabled`.

```
botonAgregar:function(){

            $('#add').click(function() {
                if (seleccionados.length < 7) {
                    var valor = $('.dep_val select:enabled').val();
                    valor != null ? seleccionados.push(valor) : null;
                    $('.idDepreciacion').prop('disabled', true);
                    MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
                }
                if (seleccionados.length == 6) $('#add').prop('disabled', true);
                //MantProyecto.cargaCombo();
            });
        }
```